# How to change a certain element in a LInked List?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to change the first and last name on my Link list but when I call the set method it doesn't change the first and last name.  In addition, I already made my deposit, withdraw methods but I'm unable to call them from my linked list. All of it is in a while loop and if the user enters Q as a command then the program should quit. I made my boolean after the while loop and me pressing Q doesn't quit the program.
            LinkedList bankRecords = new LinkedList<>();

```
        bankRecords.add(new Customer2("James", "Shown", 150));

        bankRecords.add(new Customer2("Carl", "Bob",250));

Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Command");
String x=input.nextLine();

while(true){
if(x.equals("a")){
    printList(bankRecords);
}else if(bankRecords.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Records are empty");
}
if(x.equals("r")){
    bankRecords.removeLast();
    }
if(x.equals("f")){
    bankRecords.set(bankRecords.size()-1, bankRecords.getFirst().setFirstName("Jack"));
    printList(bankRecords);

}
if(x.equals("l")){
    bankRecords.set(bankRecords.size(), bankRecords.getLast().setLastName("Kyle"));
}
if(x.equals("d")){
bankRecords.
}
if(x.equals(w)){

}
if(x.equals("n")){
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    String name=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Last name");
    String lname=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Balance:");
    int balance=input.nextInt();
    bankRecords.add(new Customer2(name, lname, balance));
}


    if(x.equals("s")){
        System.out.println("Enter first name");
        String fname=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Last name");
        String lname=input.nextLine();

            if(bankRecords.contains(fname)){

            }
        }
    }
if(x.equals("q")){
    false;
}



        public static void printList(LinkedList<Customer2> list) {

        for (Customer2 data : list) {

        System.out.println(data.getFirstName()+"\t"+data.getLastName()+"\t"+data.getAccountBalance());

        }

        }

        }
```

AccountClass

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int accountBalance;
public int total=0;
public Customer2(String fName, String lName, int balance){
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    accountBalance = balance;
}
public void setFirstName(String newFirstName){
    firstName = newFirstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String newLastName){
    lastName = newLastName;
    }
public String getFirstName() {

return firstName;

}

public String getLastName() {

return lastName;

}



public double getAccountBalance() {

return accountBalance;

}
public void withdraw(int amount){
    total=accountBalance-amount;
    accountBalance=total;

}
public void deposit(int amount){
    total=accountBalance+amount;
    accountBalance=total;
}



public void menu(){

        System.out.println("a  Show all records");
        System.out.println("r  Remove the current record");
        System.out.println("f  Change the first name in the current record");
        System.out.println("l  Change the last name in the current record");
        System.out.println("n  Add a new record");
        System.out.println("d  Add a deposit to the current record");
        System.out.println("w  Make a withdrawal from the current record");
        System.out.println("s Select a record from the record list to become the current record");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "my code doesn't work"? Do you get error/exception/wrong result? Also focus on [one problem per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: Provide stacktraces or IDE errors

Comment: Please reformat your code

Comment: What do you think the statement `false;` is supposed to achieve?

Comment: My bad, so I have the methods done for my withdraw, deposit class but when I try to call my deposit class it doesn't work. In addition, I tried to change the first and last name of the names entered in the record but when I get sometype of error.

Comment: The false; statement is suppose to stop the while loop. So if the user enters the "q" command then it should stop looping.

Comment: But it doesn't compile, does it? Because `false` is not a statement. It's a boolean literal. To stop a loop the loop has to use a *variable* as its condition, and then you assign a new value to that *variable*. It's important to solve all compile problems first. Also, you should be more specific (and [edit] your question with the details, rather than add them in comments) about what "doesn't work" means. "It does X instead of doing Y". Or "I get this error (copy and paste the error)".

Comment: What is the option f and l for ? And as per your program, what is your current record logically? Is it the last record you added to the list?

Comment: if the user enters option f then he would be able to change the first name and if he enters L then he should be able to change the last name.Yes the last record entered be comes the current record and all the other commands follow that. So entering f or L would change the first and last name of the current record. Command S should be able to change the current record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your program and it is incomplete. Looks like you're in the middle of your development and you've pasted the incomplete code.
Usually to start with its a good practice to structure your code first and add comment/todo lines to show what needs to be done. 
Then fill out those todo lines one by one to complete your code.

For your error of the program not exiting on pressing q option, try below

```
if (x.equals("q")) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
```

Below is the way to go for option f and l

```
    if (x.equals("f")) {
        Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
        currentRecord.setFirstName("Jack");
    }
    if (x.equals("l")) {
        Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
        currentRecord.setLastName("Kyle");
    }
```

below is the way to go for options d and w

```
        if (x.equals("d")) {
            Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
            currentRecord.deposit(20);
        }
        if (x.equals("w")) {
            Customer2 currentRecord = bankRecords.getLast();
            currentRecord.withdraw(10);
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. How would I call my deposit and withdraw methods.

Comment: updated the answer. Check it for withdraw and deposit.

Comment: Thanks I figured out the deposit and withdraw methods

Comment: If I wanted to change the current record how would I do that. So lets say I pressed "s" and wanted my first record to be the current one. After I did that and I press "f" I should be able to change the first name of the first record since that is the current one.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting requirement. For this, you may need to change your class design a bit. 
below code might give you some idea.
http://ideone.com/dJsW1S.
Although the link will not compile in ideone.com because it needs filename to be same as class name. But it will give you an idea of how to approach your specific problem in the last comment above.